# Qual è il significato di "riporto" in questa frase?

Tags: word-meaning

Nel libro autobiografico *Un grande avvenire dietro le spalle* di Vittorio Gassman ho letto:

> Dopo una mezz'ora che mi stavo arrabattando con le fasce, si formò intorno a me un capannello di volti assorti: mi guardavano come un animale di specie sconosciuta; qualche anima pietosa mi rivelò la chiave dell'operazione, il movimento elicoidale da dare alle fasce, la proporzione dei **riporti**.

La frase si riferisce all'uniforme militare che doveva indossare Gassman.

Ho letto tutte le accezioni di ["riporto" nel vocabolario Treccani](http://www.treccani.it/vocabolario/riporto/), ma non riesco a capirne il significato in questa frase. Me lo sapreste spiegare?

Comment: Era un'uniforme da ufficiale? Il riporto riferito alle fasce fa pensare al modo in cui, obbligatoriamente, queste ultime devono essere ripiegate, ma credo ci sia bisogno di qualcuno esperto in uniformi (il linguaggio, qui, è "tecnico").

Comment: @Benedetta: Si tratta della Seconda Guerra Mondiale. Ho pensato che le "fasce" fossero le "fasce mollettiere" di cui si parla cui: http://www.esercito.difesa.it/storia/pagine/uniformi-della-seconda-guerra-mondiale.aspx (per quello che si spiega sul movimento elicoidale).

Answer (score 3, accepted):

"Le fasce" normalmente si riferisce alle *fasce mollettiere*. Nel nostro esercito i modi di avvolgerle erano due a seconda del corpo di appartenenza: a spirale semplice o a spina di pesce. In entrambi i modi si partiva dal ginocchio e scendeva alla caviglia per poi risalire al ginocchio. In pratica, una volta alla caviglia si deve essere a meta' della lunghezza. Se i sormonti dei vari giri (riporti) non erano fatti come si deve il soldato finiva corto prima del ginocchio o troppo lungo con un avanzo di fascia, se cercava di recuperare qualche errore mentre avvolgeva, l'aspetto delle fasce risultava disordinato. Hanno visto pure un evoluzione tra le due guerre con quelle della prima guerra più diritte ed il modello adottato in seguito (mod.29) era sagomato e più largo in centro che alle estremità e laccetti ai due capi  Probabilmente uno degli elementi dell'uniforme più maledetti da ogni soldato obbligato ad usarle (e la fonte di questo è mio padre che se le ritrovò all'addestramento di base nel nostro disastrato esercito del dopoguerra)

PS: anche eserciti di altre nazionalità usavano le fasce ma i regolamenti in proposito ed il metodo di avvolgerle non sono gli stessi per tutti.

[image]

Comment: Quindi i "riporti" erano i giri delle fasce?

Comment: @charo, i sormonti di un giro su quello precedente

Comment: @ErikvanDoren Ho aggiunto un'immagine che può chiarire di che si sta parlando; libero di rimuoverla se non ti va o trovi di meglio.

Comment: @egreg, credo che l'immagine sia utilissima per chi non le ha mai viste. Giusto per curiosità: fanteria tendeva ad avere la spirale semplice, alpini (e corpi di servizio in montagna) le incrociavano. Gli alpini aggiungevano il gambale di lana sotto le fasce per tenere il polpaccio al caldo. I gambali di lana erano come calzettoni senza piede. Gli arditi adottarono gambali in cuoio al di sopra delle fasce che si impigliavano troppo nel filo spinato. Pure nel secondo dopoguerra l'EI dotava ancora i soldati di fasce e pezze da piedi (corredate di pulci già dal magazzino, a quanto mi si dice).

Answer (score 0):

Premesso che la frase mi è molto oscura, un possibile significato di "riporto" in questo contesto potrebbe essere quello di un ripiego di stoffa sulle maniche, come quello che c'è alla fine dei jeans, in cui l'orlo viene ripiegato e cucito.

Comment: Come ho detto in un altro mio commento, penso che si tratti delle "fasce mollettiere" e non delle maniche. Ma se a quello che hai spiegato se lo può chiamare "riporto", potrebbe trattarsi dei pezzi di stoffa che si collocano uno sopra l'altro quando si mettono queste "fasce mollettiere"?

Comment: Sì è possibile, bisognerebbe sentire però un sarto!

Answer (score 0):

Il riporto potrebbe essere la parte che copre il primo strato. Ho notato che in vecchie foto di soldati di cavalleria le fasce sono avvolte dall'alto e in caviglia hanno un doppio giro. Ritengo che la scelta dipenda dal fatto che la pressione della staffa sia prevalente in basso e la pressione con sfregamento dello staffile sullo stinco, che avviene verso l'alto, in questo modo non arriccia il bordo della fascia, che appare come tegole montate dal basso verso il colmo del tetto.

Comment: Benvenuto su Italian.SE e grazie della risposta, @Enrico. Non capisco bene però perché si dovrebbe chiamare "riporto" a questo.